# Arduino, 74HC595N, magic

Tags: arduino-uno, shift-register

Good day

I'm playing with Arduino and shift register chip 74HC595N and already tried many different ways to solve my problem, but still to luck :(

So that is my current simple scheme:
[image: Scheme]

Arduino 2,3,4 ports connected to data, clock and latch pins of 74HC595N. I've connected only first two output pins of chip to make minimum power consumption and to simplify this example as much as possible.

That is my sketch:

```
const int latchPin = 4; //Pin connected to ST_CP of 74HC595
const int clockPin = 3; //Pin connected to SH_CP of 74HC595
const int dataPin = 2;  //Pin connected to DS of 74HC595

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(latchPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(clockPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dataPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);  
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("ON");
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
  send(B10000001);
  Serial.println("OFF");
  digitalWrite(13, LOW);
  send(B01000010);
}

void send(byte d) {
  Serial.println(d);
  digitalWrite(latchPin, LOW); 
  shiftOut(dataPin, clockPin, MSBFIRST, d);
  delay(1000);
  digitalWrite(latchPin, HIGH);
}
```

And the problem is: sometimes leds are blinking but very unstable. Sometimes it's not working at all, sometimes only first led is blinking, but second one is not. Sometimes opposite - second led is blinking, first one is not. Sometimes one of led is blink very fast (just flash instead of 1 second delay).
If I touch wires and elements on breadboard - something changing. Even without touching anything - situation changing. It seems like problem is somewhere in connection or power supply and I've already tried to except it: tried few different breadboard, two different 595 chips, different wires and resistors, tried Arduino Uno, Mega and nano. Even tried atmega328p standalone, tried power it from USB, from 9v battery, old mobile charger (5.4V, 650 mA), tried to power arduino with external source (12V, 1A). In all cases the problem still exists.

I've already read a lot about power supply for Arduino, but I think at least few of the ways I've already tried to supply power is good enough for 595 chip and two LEDs - isn't it?

Please, advice me what else can I try?

Comment: Try moving the "delay(1000)" in send() to the loop() instead.

Comment: You haven't tied the OE pin (13) to ground.

Comment: @MikaelPatel: I've tried many different variants and nothing helped except Gerben's advice :)

Comment: @Gerben, Thanks a lot - seems like OE and MR pins was the reason. I'm still experimenting, but seems like that it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even this is quite old, to help others as well:

As you already did, pin 13 (output enable, active low) to ground and pin 10 (master reset, active LOW) to HIGH, to disable reset.